# How to calculate shortest distance from path?

Tags: java, math, coordinates

I have 2 coordinates (A1 and A2), connected by a straight line (my path). How can I calculate the shortest distance of a given coordinate (B1 or B2) from the straight line?

[image: A1 and A2 connected by straight line]

Comment: this is math question not java?

Comment: Consult google or a good math book

Comment: I'm fairly new with java (and also bad in math). Not sure which function available I should use.

Comment: @UnholySheep, I've tried. Most of the results are distance between A1 or A2. None are the result I'm looking for

Comment: I believe that this question is off topic for Stack Overflow as it is more of a maths question than a programming one.  Perhaps try our sister site for [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Google for *dot product*, that's basically what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Mathematically** :

   As explained in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line)
   the shortest distance between a line and a dot, can be calculated as
   follows:

> If the line passes through two points P1=(x1,y1) and P2=(x2,y2) then the distance of (x0,y0) from the line is:
>   [image: Blockquote]

2. **Java implimentaion**

   ```
   class Point {
     double x,y;

     Point(double pX, double pY){
       this.x= pX;
       this.y= pY;
     }

     public double distance(Point A1, Point A2){
       double numerator = Math.abs((A2.y - A1.y)*this.x + (A2.x - A1.x)*this.y + A2.x*A1.y - A2.y*A1.x);
       double denominator = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(A2.y - A1.y,2) + Math.pow(A2.x - A1.x,2));

       return numerator/denominator;       
     }

   }
   ```

To calculate the distance between `Point B` and the line defined by `Points A1` and `A2`, you use the method `distance` like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Point A1 = new Point(0,3);
    Point A2 = new Point(2,0);
    Point B = new Point(0,0);

    System.out.println(
        B.distance(A1,A2)
    );
}
```

And [here](http://ideone.com/ZdxLjc) is the code up and running in [ideone](http://ideone.com/ZdxLjc).

But pleas go buck to the basics, chose some good and funny coding book or tut and give it a go, happy coding :)